# What assumptions/properties, if any, characterize the Gaussian copula

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, copula

**I would like to know what assumptions and/or properties characterize the Gaussian copula.** I am interested in the case of arbitrary dimensionality, and am not so interested in properties specific to the bivariate case.

## What do I mean by characterizing assumption/property?

Many univariate distributions have a "characterizing assumption", i.e. if we assume our variable is a count of independent events happening in a given time, and we assume each event has the same mean rate of happening, then our variable is Poisson distributed.

Alternatively, we might characterize the distribution by a property we want it to have: if we know the mean and variance of continuous real-valued data, but nothing else, then the normal distribution is the maximum entropy distribution for that information.

## Some examples

It could be that the Gaussian copula is "the maximum entropy copula with 0 tail dependence" [I have no idea if that is true]

For the bivariate FGM copula, it has a nice characterization that intuitively amounts to "the closest to being independent two variables can be, if they have a given correlation". ("A characterization of Farlie-Gumbel-Morgenstern distributions via spearman's rho and chi-square divergence", Roger B. Nelson).

## Motivation

I want a conceptual way to understand the extent to which a Gaussian copula fits a given situation or not, and the degree to which its use is "natural".  Right now, the only conceptual litmus test I have for its validity is tail dependence; but its not the only copula with 0 tail dependence, so why should I pick it among the choices?  And if/when I am forced to pick it for practical reasons, what have I lost in doing so?  [These questions don't need to be answered]